# padding spaces inside/ in the middle of string to specific number of characters

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of strings that should each have 8 alphanumeric characters. They might include one or more spaces *within* the string, not right or left.

For those strings that are less than 8 characters, I'd like to pad the existing spaces, so that in the end all strings have 8 characters. The spaces / padding shall remain *within* the string. (Background: this is related to UK post codes)

My approach is convoluted and possibly flawed, below an example vector and desired output.

```r
## x can take any alphanumeric value
x <- c("xxx xxx", "xx xxx", "x  xxx", "xxx  xxx", "xx   xxx", "xxxxxxxx")

## missing number of spaces
s_miss <- 8 - nchar(x)
## numbers of spaces
s_pres <- stringr::str_count(x, "\\s")

## now here is a convoluted function
## if a space is found, the missing spaces will be added to the already present spaces
padded <- sapply(1: length(x), function(i){
    gsub("\\s+", paste(rep(" ", s_pres[i] + s_miss[i]), collapse = ""), x[i])})

## desired output 
padded
#> [1] "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "x    xxx" "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "xxxxxxxx"
nchar(padded)
#> [1] 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
regmatches(x, regexpr(' ', x)) <- strrep(' ', 9 - nchar(x))
x
[1] "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "x    xxx" "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "xxxxxxxx"
```

Or even:

```
 stringr::str_replace(x, ' ', strrep(' ', 9 - nchar(x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
pa <- sapply(x, \(y) sub(" ", strrep(" ", 9 - nchar(y)), y))
pa
#  xxx xxx     xx xxx     x  xxx   xxx  xxx   xx   xxx   xxxxxxxx 
#"xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "x    xxx" "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "xxxxxxxx" 

nchar(pa)
# xxx xxx   xx xxx   x  xxx xxx  xxx xx   xxx xxxxxxxx 
#       8        8        8        8        8        8
```

Comment: this is amazing - but I don't really understand where the `b` comes into play? (this referred to your first solution, now not visible any more

Comment: In the first way I used Map and b was `9 - nchar(x)` but I thought it was simpler to make this inside sapply.

Comment: was difficult to decide which to accept - onyambu and you both had the idea with 9-nchar(), amazing! thanks

Comment: It was not only to increase the 8 by the number of removed space in `sub` it was also to remove the `+` after `\\s+` what allows to know easily how many spaces have been removed. Maybe have a look on the timestamps who was first.

Answer (score 2):

We may use `sprintf` with `sub` in `base R` (using `R 4.2.0`)

```
x1 <- sub("^(\\s+)(\\S+)", "\\2\\1", sprintf('%8s', x))
```

-output

```
> x1
[1] "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "x    xxx" "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "xxxxxxxx"
> nchar(x1)
[1] 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Comment: `sprintf('%8s', x)`, no space, and everything's fine.

Comment: @Chris For me, it is working fine though

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option (but might not be that efficient)

```
> (s <- sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), function(x) paste0(x, collapse = strrep(" ", 8 - sum(nchar(x))))))
[1] "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "x    xxx" "xxx  xxx" "xx   xxx" "xxxxxxxx"

> nchar(s)
[1] 8 8 8 8 8 8
```